# Modify CoreResultsWebPart XML data before it is transformed?

Tags: web-part, search, custom, search-results

I'm extending CoreResultsWebPart. Do I have an opportunity to modify the search results XML before it is transformed (against the XSL)?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I'm trying to do the same thing.